Error installing tidyverse package due to zip files
I receive the following error below when trying to install tidyverse. I have successfully installed other packages.
Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'openssl/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Could you kindly assist? I am new to RStudio. This is for windows
I tried removing the install from the history pane but I still get the the same error

Hi Margaret.  Welcome to SO!  It looks like your download of openssl failed, but it's impossible to be sure because your example is not reproducible.  Please start a new R session, type install.packages("tidyverse") (and hit return).  Then copy-and-paste everything that appears in the console and add it to your question.  Then we will be able to help you further.

Alternatively, as an attempted quick fix, try install.packages("openssl") (return) followed by install.packages('tidyverse") (return).  That might or might not solve the problem. This post will help you construct a minimal reproducible example.

hi! can you please paste the output of sessionInfo() and install.packages("openssl")? we can help more with more detail
